# SAS : How to use loop with date

Tags: loops, date, sas, sas-macro

I need to do inner join with a dataset which has date and month in its name, i.e.
Account_2019_10 (as in Oct 2019).
I need to perform this inner join in a loop for each month from a specific month-year till today's month-year.(i.e. from Sept 2019 till July 2020). Considering the dataset has the month & year in the above format (2019_10 for Oct 2019), how would i perform this loop and append all the results in a group for that month-year?

Comment: Can you post an example of what your data looks like and what you want the result to be? Makes it easier to help you.

Comment: The dataset (e.g Account_2019_10) has 3 columns: Accoun No, Stage (1/2/3), Score (no between 0 and  700). I would like to see the movements of accounts in stage 1 (for eg) in 2019_10 through to 2020_07

Comment: @drycut The dataset (e.g Account_2019_10) has 3 columns: Accoun No, Stage (1/2/3), Score (no between 0 and 700). I would like to see the movements of accounts in stage 1 (for eg) each month.i am not sure how i will loop the following and get the desired result:proc sql; create table Final as select count(d.acc_unit_id), e.stage from Output as d inner join Table_ACCOUNT_yyyy_mm as e on d.accg_unit_id = e.accg_unit_id group by e.calculated_stage; run; where this query needs to loop for all  months (mm) and year (yyyy) to date starting Sept 2019 and have results for each month grouped in stages

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of the dataset being referenced you will need to use some code generation.  Typically just by using macro variables in place of the dataset name(s).

To loop over dates using an offset value and the INTNX() function.  You can use INTCK() to determine how many months to generate.

```
 data _null_;
   start = '01OCT2019'd ;
   end = '01JUL2020'd ;
   length name $32 names $1000;
   do offset=0 to intck('month',start,end);
      date=intnx('month',start,offset);
      name='account_'||translate(put(date,yymm7.),'_','M');
      names=catx(' ',names,name);
   end;
   call symputx('names',names);
 run;
```

Now that you have this list of dataset names you can use it in your code to combine the datasets.

```
 data all;
    set &names ;
 run;
```

If your monthly tables do not actually have a variable already that indicates the month you can add one by using the INDSNAME= option of the SET statement. Note that the variable created by that option is not saved so you need to copy the value.

```
 data all;
    length dsname $41 ;
    set &names indsname=dsname;
    month = dsname;
 run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although i am not sure how i will loop the following and get the desired result:     proc sql;
create table Final as select
count(d.acc_unit_id), e.stage from Output as d
inner join
Table_ACCOUNT_yyyy_mm as e
on d.accg_unit_id = e.accg_unit_id
group by e.calculated_stage;
run;   where this sql query needs to loop for all the months (mm) and year (yyyy) to date starting Sept 2019 and have results for each month grouped in stages

Comment: How large are the ACCOUNT monthly tables?  Why not just combine them first and then run your SQL code using the combined dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL data dictionary to identify the data sets containing a *yyyy_mm* construct.
Select them into a macro variable that will be used to combine all the data sets in a `SET` statement with `INDSNAME` option.

Example:

```
%macro makefakedata();

  %local year month amount;

  %do year = 2019 %to 2020;
    %do month = 1 %to 12;
      data work.account_&year._%sysfunc(putn(&month,z2.));
        do id = 1 to 10;
          amount = 100 * %sysfunc(monotonic()) + id;
          output;
        end;
      run;
    %end;
  %end;

%mend;

data work.foo_bar;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

%makefakedata;

ods listing;

proc sql noprint;
  select 
    catx('.', libname, memname) as dataset
  , input (
      cats ( substr ( memname, index(memname,'_')+1 ) , '_01' )
      , ? YYMMDD10.
    ) as month
  into
    :datasets separated by ' '
  , :months   separated by ' '
  from
    dictionary.tables
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and index(memname,'_')
  having
    month
  ;  

%put &=datasets;
%put &=months;


data all_month_named_data;
  set &datasets indsname=from;
   
  source = from;
  month = input (
      cats ( substr ( source, index(source,'_')+1 ) , '_01' )
      , YYMMDD10.);

  format month yymm7.;
run;
```